# List out of range during a string split function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get the values from a string split with aa specific index, but it works fine for the 0 index, when i try to access the 1st index, it throws list index out of range

```
for child in root:  
    for child1 in child: 
      if(child1.tag == "mxCell"): 
        id = child1.attrib['id'] 
        id_2 = child1.attrib['id'] 
        split_data = id.split('-')[0] + 'Z'
```

i am using a xml.etree since its an XML file

In the above code, when i try to access the 1st index it throws an error. ie. `split_data = id.split('-')[1] + 'Z'`
or when i try to access the value by `split_data_ = id.split('-')` `print(split_data_[1])` it throws an error

Comment: Have you looked at what `split_data_` is when it raises an exception? We can't look because you didn't include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `id.split('-')[0]` will get the string before `-`, `[1]` will get the string after and will error if there is no `-`. If the text doesn't have a `-` and you want to safely get the element try `id.split('-')[-1]` to always get the last element

Comment: the type(split_data_) is a list

Comment: Yes, but *how long* is that list?

Comment: i cross checked with my data in the loop.  ``` id = child1.attrib['id'] ``` . every id contains a '-'

Comment: Thanks @TenaciousB it worked. But i wonder why it can't get the 1st index even if there is an occurance

Comment: @SrinivasanRamesh you might be able to find the elements causing the error if you do `split_data = id.split('-') try: item = id.split('-')[1] except: print(split_data)` and see what it prints

Answer (score 0):

That error implies not all of the `id` elements have `-` characters in them. If you use `[-1]` instead of `[1]` this will safely grab the last element in the list, even if the list only has one item:

```py
split_data = id.split('-')[-1] + 'Z'
```

To find the element(s) causing the problem you can do:

```py
split_data = id.split('-')
try:
    item = id.split('-')[1] # try to access index 1
except:
    print(id) # print the offending item
    print(split_data) # see if it split correctly
```